# SQLite Query to average over days?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that has integer values associated with date-time objects over minute intervals.

I want to be able to query between `12:00am - 10:00am` over the past `14 days` the **average** of those **integer** columns. How is this possible?

So essentialy loop through each day that I have for the past 14 days and average the values between those date ranges.

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(Yourintegerfield) AS Avg_for_last_14_days
  FROM Yourtable
 WHERE strftime('%H-%M-%S',yourdatetimefield ) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '10:00:00'
   AND  date('now') <= datetime( strftime('%Y-%M-%D', yourdatetimefield ), '+14 days' );
```

Comment: Should be '%Y-%m-%d' as m refers to month and d refers to the day.  M=minute, D=american date.